# Google Play Console: be eligible for promotion (screenshots)

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I'm getting this message in Google Play Console:

> To be eligible for promotion, include at least 4 screenshots, with at
> least 3 in 16:9 or 9:16 and at least 1080 px.

Pointing to these guidelines: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9866151#screenshots&zippy=%2Cscreenshots

I'm not exactly sure if it's suggesting me to upload screenshots with that size or if it's just a default message. The thing is that I have 9:16 with at least 1080px.

Link to check images: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.drodriguez.time_tap